# Side bar image disappearing when page reload Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I'm using vue-router to navigate between the menus and doing some request with axios. Whenever the page reloads, the image on the side bar dissapears. I'm not sure what's causing this. Thanks in advance.

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER reload**

[image]

```
<aside class="main-sidebar elevation-4" style="background-color:#F4F6F9"> 
<a href="#" class="brand-link">
  <img src="./img/logo.png"  class="brand-image img-thumbnail elevation-3">
  <img src="./img/uthm.png"  class="brand-image img-thumbnail elevation-3">
       <br>
</a> 
</aside>
```

Comment: You need to provide code.

Comment: @RichardAyotte done

Answer (score 0):

Your reload may possibly take you a level deeper into your site and your links to you images are now becoming invalid.

eg.

```
http://www.example.com/page1

# Works fine so far
../path/to/image.jpg
```

on reload:

```
http://www.example.com/page1/page2

# Your image link now needs to revert back one level
../../path/to/image.jpg
```

I had a similar issue, where my index page worked fine but as soon as I went a directory in it freaked out, I realised I needed a better way to assign img src's

**Update**
My fix was to use an inbuilt command in laravel that gave the root path to the file. You might have to find if Vue has a similar function to direct always to the root folder no matter where you are.

A quick fix is to give the full directory path

```
# instead of the relative path
../path/to/image.com

# Try
http://example.com/root/path/to/image.jpg

# or if offline

http://127.0.0.1/root/path/to/image.jpg
```

Comment: yep its true, i just realised it ! any ways to overcome this?

Comment: I was working on a laravel project which I think was PHP. Vue might have a special function to call that tells the route the root of your project, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give us more details .
I will participate in this with my sugestion , if you are using vue-router and when you reload the page ,did the link change , i know for sure that is your problem
As an example , when your reload this url  (https://127.0.0.1/test/) , it will be (https://127.0.0.1/test/#/) the path that you are loading your pictures from  will change , so you need to configure your app.js in this path (resources\assets\js) , and you need to add this line to your route .

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode:'history',
  routes 

})
```

if you do so , the url will be the some after you reload your page.